# php array variable not working

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the following variable into an array which basically contains a list of numbers separated by spaces. When I attempt to apply basic array formulas that should work it makes each individual number into a separate array. How would I get all the numbers into one array?

Partial Code:

```
echo "<h2>Table:</h2>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i = 0; $i < $fields_num; $i++) {
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
}

echo "</tr>\n";

// printing table rows
$rn = 0;
$projsum = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $rn = $rn + 1;
    if($rn == 1) {
        $presproj = $row[0];
        $projrow = 1;
    }
    if($row[0] != $rowm1[0]) { // if present row col 1 differs from Previous  
        $col = 0;
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($rowm1 as $cell) {
            $col = $col + 1;
            if($col == 1) {
                echo "<td><small>Total</small></td>";
            } elseif($col < count($rowm1)) {
                echo "<td><small></small></td>";

            } else {
                echo "<td><small>";
                echo $projsum;
                echo "</small></td>";
                $projsum = 0;

            }
            $projrow = 1;

        }
        echo "</tr>\n";

    }

    echo "<tr>";
    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    $it = 0;
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        $it = $it + 1;
        if(($it == 1) && ($projrow != 1)) {
            echo "<td><small></small></td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td><small>" . $cell . "</small></td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";

    $rowm1 = $row;
    $projrow = $projrow + 1;
    $projsum = $projsum + $row[count($row) - 1];
    $sample .= End(end($row));
    echo $sample;

}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Variable:

```
$projsum=$projsum + $row[count($row)-1];
```

Using explode to make an array creates the following:
$projsum_array = explode(" ", $projsum);

Array ( [0] => 62.92 ) Array ( [0] => 212.92 ) Array ( [0] => 238 ) Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 151.58 ) Array ( [0] => 184.16 ) Array ( [0] => 713.99 ) Array ( [0] => 859.07 ) Array ( [0] => 864.32 ) Array ( [0] => 866.32 ) Array ( [0] => 897.57 ) Array ( [0] => 921.15 ) Array ( [0] => 924.15 ) Array ( [0] => 927.48 ) Array ( [0] => 944.15 ) Array ( [0] => 11 ) Array ( [0] => 50.83 )

Comment: Show us the actual contents of the variable, not how it's set. The code you gave us means nothing to anyone that doesn't know anything about your project (Including everyone on this site)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton here is what it looks like when I try to use explode for the vairable: It shows all the numbers in individual arrays: Array ( [0] => 62.92 ) Array ( [0] => 212.92 ) Array ( [0] => 238 ) Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 151.58 ) Array ( [0] => 184.16 ) Array ( [0] => 713.99 ) Array ( [0] => 859.07 ) Array ( [0] => 864.32 ) Array ( [0] => 866.32 ) Array ( [0] => 897.57 ) Array ( [0] => 921.15 ) Array ( [0] => 924.15 ) Array ( [0] => 927.48 ) Array ( [0] => 944.15 ) Array ( [0] => 11 ) Array ( [0] => 50.83 )

Comment: Paste it in the question with some formatting.

Comment: Is it 50.83 you are trying to get?

Comment: We're missing too much information.  What is `$row`?  How is it formatted?  What is `$projsum`'s initial condition?  We need (a) the entire relevant block of code, (b) and your expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your string into an array you can use `explode()`.

Check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) about this.

```
$projsum_array = explode(" ", $projsum);
```

Comment: this is what i tired and it puts each number into individual arrays rather then one single array

Comment: Can you answer the questions posted above?

Comment: @user8345269 that doesn't make sense, `explode()` _can't_ make multiple arrays

Comment: When I use $projsum_array = explode(" ", $projsum); it shows this

Array ( [0] => 62.92 ) Array ( [0] => 212.92 ) Array ( [0] => 238 ) Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 151.58 ) Array ( [0] => 184.16 ) Array ( [0] => 713.99 ) Array ( [0] => 859.07 ) Array ( [0] => 864.32 ) Array ( [0] => 866.32 ) Array ( [0] => 897.57 ) Array ( [0] => 921.15 ) Array ( [0] => 924.15 ) Array ( [0] => 927.48 ) Array ( [0] => 944.15 ) Array ( [0] => 11 ) Array ( [0] => 50.83 )

Comment: @user8345269 What is $projsum BEFORE you explode it?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton when i use echo $projsum;  it shows the list of numbers like this:  62.92 212.92 238 1 151.58 184.16 713.99 859.07 864.32 866.32 897.57 921.15 924.15 927.48 944.15 11 50.83 56.83 58.16

Comment: @user8345269 is this a string? When I explode it as a string it returns all of the numbers in 1 array as separate keys.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I did not put in the exact numbers for the variable $projsum...its basically adding the cell values of each row in my table which can change so the numbers can change for $projsum as well. However, it is storing them correctly and when I echo the variable in the end it displays them all like i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me as what you are looking for is this:

```
$projsum .=  End($row);
```

Notice the `.=` means keep projsum and add.
And end() will get the last item in the array.

Edit: if it's the 50.83 from your array you are trying to get then it's one level lower in the array so you need to use

```
$projsum .=  End(end($row));
```

It will throw an waening notice but you can suppress it with @ if you are sure the array does not change in structure.

Comment: Ultimately, yes I would like to get the last number of the $projsum variable that at the moment when echoed is a list of numbers. However, I cant seem to get it even into a single array as seen above. I tried you method but nothing showed up when I echoed the variable to check it

Comment: See here on a smaller version of your array. It seems to work. https://3v4l.org/A0su0 or do I missread your array?

Comment: I tried this and it put each individual number into float(#) and so on

Comment: What? I don't understand.

Comment: Using 
Var_dump($projsum);
Echo @end(end($projsum));  

It looks like this now:

float(62.92) float(212.92) float(238) float(1) float(151.58) float(184.16) float(713.99) float(859.07) float(864.32) float(866.32) float(897.57) float(921.15) float(924.15) float(927.48) float(944.15) float(11) float(50.83) float(56.83) float(58.16) float(8) float(9) float(10) float(19.83) float(4.5) float(5) float(26.5) float(27.5) float(57.25) float(58.25)

Comment: See here: https://3v4l.org/5bPnf I see now that I used .= Wrongly it should probably be +=

Comment: this changed everything to 1